# Propositional Logic - Conditional Proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm confused doing one problem. The problem is to show that

$$(P\vee Q \implies R) \implies (P\wedge Q \implies R)$$
using Rule C.P. What I have done so far:

Assumed antecedent of the conclusion as an assumed premise.

\begin{align*} &(1) \; P \wedge Q  &&\text{Rule P (Assumed)} \\
&(2) \; P        &&\text{Rule T (1) Simplification} \; P\wedge Q \implies P \\
&(3)\; P\vee Q \implies R && \text{Rule P} \\
    &(4) \; Q        &&\text{Rule T (1) Simplification} \; P\wedge Q \implies Q \end{align*}

What should I do next?

Comment: Please don't delete your question after receiving a helpful answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{aligned}[t]
1.&\\2.&\\3.&\\4.&\\5.&\\6.&
\end{aligned}
\quad
\begin{aligned}[t]
&(P \vee Q) \to R\\
&P \wedge Q \\
&P \\
&P \vee Q \\
&R\\
&(P \wedge Q)\to R
\end{aligned}
\qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
&\text{A}\\&\text{PA}\\&\text{2, Simp}\\&\text{3, Add}\\&\text{1, 4, MP}\\&\text{2$-$5, CP}
\end{aligned}
$$

**Notation:** A for assumption; PA for provisional assumption; Simp for simplification; Add for addition; MP for *modus ponens*; CP for conditional proof.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $P \lor Q \rightarrow R$. Now we start with $P \land Q$:

$$P \land Q \rightarrow P \quad \text{by simplification}$$
$$P \rightarrow P \lor Q \quad \text{by addition}$$
$$P \lor Q \rightarrow R \quad \text{by assumption}$$
We conclude that $P \land Q \rightarrow R$. So we have proven the assertion in question:

$[(P \lor Q) \rightarrow R]  \Longrightarrow [(P \land Q) \rightarrow R)]$.